# htaccess 301 redirects for documents NOT pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using WordPress and I have a PDF and a Word document on my server, both documents are now out of date but are highly ranked on Google.

Is it possible to use a 301 redirect on a document? I have used 301 redirects in the past to point old URLs to new one's but have never come across this situation of using it with a document.

I'm not even sure it is permissible to do this. If not any suggestions on how I should go about this problem?

Comment: Post the sample URLs (e.g. `mysite.com/document.pdf -> mysite.com/document-page`), how many URLs are there? Give us something to work on.

Comment: I have added some further information below, hope it explains it a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Redirect 301 /old.doc http://www.example.com/
Redirect 301 /old.pdf http://www.example.com/
```

**Update**
I use the following for a WordPress blog I worked on

```
RedirectMatch 301 /old\.pdf(.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

Comment: Sorry for not supplying more information, hopefully this will help: 

The old pdf file is in this location: http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/oldfile.pdf

The new pdf is in this location on the server: http://www.example.com/sub-directory/newfile.pdf

I would like to keep the old link active as it is used in various places on the website as well ranking highly in Google.

I would just like to know how I could get the url to the old file to redirect to the new file?

Thanks for help

Comment: Try `Redirect 301 /wp-content/uploads/2010/10/oldfile.pdf http://example.com/sub-directory/newfile.pdf`? Please post your `.htaccess` if you're still having problems.

Comment: @jaffa: Move your redirect to just after the `RewriteBase /` and see if it works then.

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect 301 /wp-content/uploads/2010/10/oldfile.pdf http://example.com/sub-directory/newfile.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks Shef, tried that but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @jaffa: Did you add this before the other rules?

Comment: No I didn't. I placed it right at the bottom of the file right after the # END WordPress. Is that the wrong place? Sorry, I'm kinda new to all this

Comment: I tried moving it before too but it still doesn't work. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: @jaffa: I have tested it here, and it works perfectly fine. Please share a URL so we can take a look, or tell us how you are testing it. If you go to `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/oldfile.pdf` it must definitely redirect you to `http://example.com/sub-directory/newfile.pdf`.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. Here is a copy of my htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/CrUPc0X

I am using a Wordpress Mulitsite, would that make any difference?

Comment: Hey Shef, It works!!! I moved the rewrite just under the </IfModule> and it works. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: @jaffa: I am glad you got it resolved. Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem by clicking on the tick below the vote count on the left side of my answer. :)

Comment: I clicked the tick! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @jaffa: You clicked the tick on the other answer, but it's OK if you intended that. :)

Comment: I have tried the same code, but it does not seem to redirect my .pdf URL. If i try to redirect root url, it works, not sure what is the issue? Can you suggest?